# webcomponent style applied all in safari and firefox using webcomponentsjs

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have two custom element:

```
<name-card data-color="#000000"></name-card>
<name-card data-color="#80B88C"></name-card>
```

which I will applied their `data-color` to the style.
From I asked question before, how to get cssRules, I got the answer and added it to `attachedCallback()` for dynamic changes.

But, it just shows the right colour on chrome, other browser applied the last colour which is `#80B88C` to both.

I checked the loop in `attachedCallback()`

```
for(i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
    if(rules[i].selectorText === '.base'){
       rules[i].style.background = bgColor;
    }
}
```

and both changed the correct colour, but I still have no idea why they will applied the last colour to both elements style on safari and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact the polyfill cannot realize totally the css isolation.

So the CSS stylesheet that you add in a polyfilled Shadow DOM is in fact applied to the whole document. When the same name rule is used twice, the last one wins. That's why you observe this behaviour in Safari and Firefox.

There's a workaround to this issue in your case, which deals with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements:

**Curent Solution**

- Generate a more specific `cssRule` which includes the specific color:

*Inside the `attachedCallback()` function:*

```
sheet.insertRule( '[data-color=' + bgColor + '] .base::before { background: ' + bgColor + ' ; }', sheet.length )
```

---

**Future Solution**

When the the CSS 3 specification for `attr()` on every properties will be implemented:

- Propagate the color to the targeted elements and use the `attr()` CSS function to apply the right color, passed by attribute (`data-color` in your example).

The advantage of this solution is that it works the same way will polyfill and native implementation, and with an unlimited number or colors.

*In the `attachedCallback()` function:*

```
var targets = this.querySelectorAll( '.base' )
for ( var i = 0 ; i < targets.length ; i++ )
{
    targets[i].dataset.color = bgColor  
}
```

*In the `<style>` element:*

```
.base::before {
    background: attr( data-color )
}
```

```js
var proto = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype )
proto.createdCallback = function ()
{
  this.createShadowRoot()
  var tmpl = document.querySelector( 'template' )
  this.shadowRoot.appendChild( tmpl.content.cloneNode( true ) )
}
proto.attachedCallback = function ()
{
  //get custom color
  var bgColor = this.dataset.color

  //add it to the top-level inside Shadow DOM
  this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'section' ).dataset.color = bgColor
      
  //change the stylesheet in the next microtask
  var style = this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'style' )
  setTimeout( function () 
  {
    var sheet = style.sheet
    sheet.insertRule( '[data-color=' + bgColor 
           + '] .base::after { background: ' + bgColor + ' ; }'
           , sheet.cssRules.length )
  } )
}
document.registerElement( 'name-card', { prototype: proto } )
```

```html
<name-card data-color="red"></name-card>
<name-card data-color="green"></name-card>
<template>
  <style>
    .base::after { 
      content: '-postfix' ;
    }
  </style>
  <section>
    <div>Custom Element</div>
    <span class="base">Base element</span>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, made my day. But I use cssRules solution is because I have pseudo-elements style need to change.... I can't change `::after` or `::before` using your solution.

Comment: Seem If I want to fix this problem, the only way is re-write the css, using `div` instead of `:after` `:before` right? Then I can use the solution 1.

Comment: I can't use `background: attr(data-color)`, it shows invalid property value - a yellow triangle. Seems css `attr()` just works on `content`.

Comment: You're right, it's in the spec but not implemented yet in the borwsers! So the workaround is to use the old 2nd solution. I update my answer.

Comment: `insertRule()` will back to the problem, just works on chrome. safari and firefox show the last colour will wins. Applied the colour both of them.